# Is there a Popup class in the SDK for WP8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is there a Popup class (or similar) in the SDK for Windows Phone 8.1?

`System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup` doesn't exist since `System.Windows.Controls.` isn't available.

Of course MessageDialog and PopupMenu, are available, but none of them seem to have a default behavior of dismissable information with no buttons (and maybe even non-modal).

Must I use a custom user control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows phone-RT Popup class is member of "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives" namespace. you can define Popup in xaml as below:

```
 <Popup x:Name="ppup" IsOpen="False" Grid.Row="2" >
            <StackPanel Background="Blue" Height="100" Width="400">
                <TextBlock Text="This is Pop up control of Xaml" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold">
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
```

and in code behind you can set IsOpen property to true/false.

Comment: perfect, thanks. Programatically I couldn't find it so `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.Popup` is spot on.